# UI Angular Bootstrap typeahead hide first option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using UI Angular Bootstrap typeahead feature. I want to hide the first option. Here I would like to hide option **Alaska** from the user. How can this be done?

[image: refer this]

Comment: I don't think that it can be achieved easily. One workaround will be defining a custom filter which always removes the first element.

Comment: I dont want to remove the element from the list. I want to hide it from the user

Comment: Filter doesn't remove it. It just doesn't renders the first element in the UI

Comment: I want the element to be rendered but hidden from view

Comment: What do you mean by render, but hidden? Not rendering the first item means hidding it rght?

Comment: use css property display:none to hide it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're always wanting to hide the first result, then just put a class on the typeahead like `.hide-first-result` and then use css to hide it:

```
.hide-first-result ul > li:first-child { display: none; }
```

For example:

```
<span class="hide-first-result">
  <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the first element from your list:

```
 <input type="text" class="input-fit" 
               typeahead-on-select="selectItem($item);" 
               typeahead-min-length="3" 
               typeahead-wait-ms="1000" 
               typeahead-loading="loading" 
               ng-model="selectItem" 
               data-ng-click="resetItemInput()"
               uib-typeahead="i.name for i in items($viewValue)">
```

Then you remove the first from the success callback data:

```
        $scope.items = function(search) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            ItemService.getItems(search).then(function(data) {
                defer.resolve(data.splice(0,1));
            });
            return defer.promise;
          };
```

Comment: This is way overkill.  He's just trying to hide something, so why not use css?

Comment: This is another way. I don't see this solution would be overkill because he won't need the first option ever.

Comment: It's not a terrible way to do things, just much more than is needed given the requirements.  It would also take longer for another person to figure out what is going on, versus just seeing a well-named class like `hide-first-result` etc